# Redirect Keycloak to Custom Forgot Password

Tags: authentication, redirect, keycloak

Hi I am using Keycloak for authentication. I have one separate service for forgot password. I want to redirect keycloak to that service when Forgot Password Link is clicked.

I dont want to use keycloak's forgot password service.

Please Help.

Answer (score 3):

Keycloak's login page is built using [Freemarker](http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/) templates. These are stored in Themes folder inside Keycloak. You can edit these FLT files inside Keycloak's theme folder and make any changes you want - like adding a link to another URL/resource/etc.

The base login theme can be found here -

```
/standalone/configuration/themes/base/login/login.ftl
```

Themes can be deployed in multiple ways - as a folder/module/jar. They need to be dropped under -

```
standalone/configuration/themes
```

Comment: Find the documentation for custom templates here: http://docs.jboss.org/keycloak/docs/1.2.0.Beta1/userguide/html/themes.html

Answer (score 0):

Under `keycloak-9.0.3/themes/base/login/` you can find standard templates which names and content you can use for customization. E.g. `login-reset-password.ftl`.
Then it's recommended better to create a custom theme and under it copy/create your custom template.

At the end don't forget to change the "Login Theme" to your custom one on Keycloak Admin Panel under "Realm Settings" -> "Theme".